# Change key when looping through json

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, for-loop

is it possible to change the key when looping through objects with an external variable. Imagine it like that:

```
var data = [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Simon",
    "age": 13
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Helga",
    "age": 18
}, {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Tom",
    "age": 27
}, ]

var key = name;

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var output = data[i].key;
}
```

But this, of course, ends up with an undefined output. Goal is to build a function which can handle different loops.

Comment: Use bracket notation: `data[i][key]`

Comment: Don't forget to choose an answer when your problem has been solved! If it hasn't been solved, please update your question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access objects in JavaScript just like you do with arrays.  Here is the code you are looking for.

```js
var data = [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Simon",
    "age": 13
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Helga",
    "age": 18
}, {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Tom",
    "age": 27
}, ]

var key = "name";

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var output = data[i][key];
}
```

In reference to the other answer (which appears to have been deleted) I wouldn't recommend using foreach because it is not supported in Internet Explorer 8.

However, you could use:

```js
var key = "name";

for (var i in data) {
  if(data.hasOwnProperty(i))
  {
    var output = data[i][key];
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice answer. Yet, I wonder if you need the hasOwnProperty() check in the case of an object from JSON?  Seems like you would not, though it's probably good practice to add it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need a function like this:

```
function handleKey(objectArray, key) {
    for (var index in objectArray) {
        //do something with objectArray[index][key]
    }
}
```

Call this function like this: `handleKey(data, "name")`

The function handles the key attributes of an object array. You can customize this further based on needs, I decided to be short to keep it simple.